# LiveData returning zero instead of correct integer

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am using Room and LiveData to manage my SQLite database in my app. I need to fetch one field of data from a table, the Primary Key, autogenerated field. To do so, I am coding the following inside my activity class:

```
//Method to insert the new entry in the database
 ViewModelEntry.insert(newEntry);
 ViewModelEntry recentEntry = new ViewModelEntry(RegisterActivity.this.getApplication());

//Observing the LiveData to get the last entry cadID
 recentEntry.getLastEntry().observe(this, lastEntry -> lastCadID = lastEntry.getCadID());
 Toast.makeText(this, "lastCadID = " + lastCadID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//This should return the last ID inserted (7, for exemple) but is returning 0 instead

 Intent itemInspectionIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, InspectionActivity.class);
 itemInspectionIntent.putExtra(MEMORIAL_ITEM_ENTRY, lastCadID);
 startActivity(itemInspectionIntent);
```

Where `ViewModelEntry` is my implementation of the ViewModel class and `insert` is the implementation of the insertion of the `<NewEntry>` object into the database through the @insert Room method.

**EDIT:** Here is the implementation of the `<insert>` method>

```
//ViewModel implementation

//Presented in a code snippet below:
//public static ReportRepository repository;
 public static void insert(SchoolEntry schoolEntry) { repository.insertSchoolEntry(schoolEntry); }

//Repository implementation
public void insertSchoolEntry(SchoolEntry schoolEntry) {
        ReportDatabase.dbWriteExecutor.execute(() -> schoolEntryDao.insertEntry(schoolEntry));
    }

//DAO Implementation
    @Insert()
    void insertEntry(SchoolEntry schoolEntry);
```

Here is the implementation of `<dbWriteExecutor>` that appeared in my Repository implementation of the `<insertSchoolEntry>` method: (this one is implemented in my Database class):

```
public static final ExecutorService dbWriteExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_THREADS);
//NUMBER_THREADS = 4
```

**Edit End**

The problem happens when I try to obtain the value of the `<cadID>` field of the entry I just inserted. For some reason, this code returns me 0 instead of the value of the last entry.

These are the implementations of the `<getLastEntry>` method in my ViewModel, Repository AND DAO:

```
//ViewModel implementation
public static ReportRepository repository;

public ViewModelEntry(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new ReportRepository(application); }

 public LiveData<SchoolEntry> getLastEntry() {return repository.getLastSchoolEntry(); }


//Repository Implementation
private SchoolEntryDao schoolEntryDao;

public ReportRepository(Application application) {
        ReportDatabase db = ReportDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        schoolEntryDao = db.schoolEntryDao(); }

public LiveData<SchoolEntry> getLastSchoolEntry() { return schoolEntryDao.getLastEntry(); }


//DAO Implementation

@Query("SELECT * FROM SchoolEntry WHERE cadID == (SELECT MAX(cadID) from SchoolEntry)")
    LiveData<SchoolEntry> getLastEntry();
```

The insertion proccess works flawlessly, since I used the Database Inspector to check out if the entry was inserted. Also, when I run that SQLite query in the DB inspector, it DOES give me the entry i just recorded in my DB. Can someone help me with this situation?

Comment: Can you please share the implementation of ViewModelEntry.insert() function. Also, is your first code snippet running on the main thread?

Comment: @NavjotSinghBedi I've updated my question with the implementations you've asked for. About the snippet, I suppose it is running in the main thread. I still have some doubts about how to implement multiple threads in my app but, since before I got an error trying to access the database from the main thread, I'm almost sure this is running on it.

Answer (score 2):

**What's happening?**

Insertion is happening in the background thread and we are not waiting for the insertion to complete. This leads to the fetching of last `cadId` before the insertion, which results in a 0 value.

**Proposed Solution**

1. Enter the background thread
2. Perform Insertion `ViewModelEntry.insert(newEntry);` and wait till it is done.
3. Fetch the last inserted item `"SELECT * FROM SchoolEntry WHERE cadID == (SELECT MAX(cadID) from SchoolEntry)"`. Connect Dao LiveData to `recentEntry`, which is already being observed on the main thread.

Comment: How can I achieve that? Thread.sleep? I've read this is not a good practice, though.

Comment: You can achieve this through Kotlin Coroutine OR RxJava. They are a good component for threading in Android.

Comment: Could you give me an exemple of how can I use Completable correctly in a situation like this? I am trying but I don't think I'm using it correctly